# Jquery Conditional validation based on select text

Tags: jquery, validation, conditional-statements

I want to make the "other" field required ONLY if the selected text in the "select1" field is "other" the rule I'm trying is: `other: { required: function(element){ return $("#select1 option:selected").text() == "Other"; } }` Am i doing something wrong? Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-  validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form:first').validate({
        rules: {
          cname: {
          required: true,
        },
        select1: { valueNotEquals: "0" }
        },
        other: {
                required: function(element){
                            return $("#select1 option:selected").text() == "Other";
                        }
        },   
        messages: {
          cname: "Please enter a valid naaaammmeeee.",
      select1: "Please choose a valid option",
      other: "Please enter a valid other value",
        },
      });

       $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
        return arg != value;
        }, "Value must not equal arg.");
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>


 <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
   <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <em>*</em><input id="cname" name="cname"/>
   </p>
   <p>
   <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="0">Please choose a value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">Other</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="other">Other</label>
        <em>*</em><input id="other" name="other"/>
   </p>
       <p>
       <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
       </p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve here? Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple problems mostly related to JSON formatting:

1. one extra `closing bracket` here:

   ```
   select1: { valueNotEquals: "0" }
       },
   ```
2. One `closing bracket` missing here at the end of the `rules` definition and just before the start of `messages` definition

   return $("#select1 option:selected").text() == "Other";
                               }
               }
   **}**,
           messages: {
3. Extra `comma` at end of each options were un-necessary
4. Space in the validate.js path (this might be a typo here in the question itslef)

   here is the corrected code:

...

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form:first').validate({
    rules: {
        cname: { required: true },
        select1: { valueNotEquals: "0" },
        other: { required: function(element){
                            return $("#select1 option:selected").text() == "Other";
                            }
            }
},   
        messages: {
            cname: "Please enter a valid naaaammmeeee.",
            select1: "Please choose a valid option",
            other: { required: "Please enter a valid other value"}
            }
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks Amar. That worked a treat. I'm relatively new to JQuery, and haven't gotten to grips with all the syntax rules just yet. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Cheers man :) Now, you should accept the answer and make it a habit to do so in future too if you feel satisfied with the answer. I am saying in general :)

Comment: Sorry Amar, though the validation is now working, my messages are being ignored, and the default "This field is required" is coming through. Is there something else missing here?

Comment: try it now. I have edited the code for now, need to change the explanation a bit, in the mean time you test the code above.

Comment: just back on this today. No that didn't seem to work. Cheers.

Comment: http://ge.tt/8Vt98rT/v/0?c
Here I have the modified file for you. I'm on Chrome in Ububtu, and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

updated the answer find a demo at fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3jrTM/

```
$('form:first').validate({
rules: {
    cname: {
        required: true
    },
    select1: {
        valueNotEquals: "0"
    },
    other: {
        required: function(element) {
            return $("#select1 option:selected").text() == "Other";
        }
    },
},
messages: {
    cname: "Please enter a valid naaaammmeeee.",
    select1: "Please choose a valid option",
    other: "Please enter a valid other value"
}

});

$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg) {
return arg != value;
}, "Value must not equal arg.");​
```

Comment: Thanks Jai. That part is working. It's the following rule that's giving me problems.

Comment: Sorry Jai, I was away for a day. Thanks you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function() {
   var text = $('select option:selected').text();​​​​​​​​​
   if(text == 'Other') {
       $('input[name=other]').attr('disabled', false);        
    }
  });
```

​is this what you mean

Comment: Apologies if the description is unclear. I want to make the "other" field required ONLY if the selected text in the "select1" field is "other" the rule I'm trying is:                                              other: {
                required: function(element){
       return $("#select1 option:selected").text() == "Other";
       }
        },

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the value of your option which contains the "0".

```
<option>Select here someting</option>
```

When a option contains no value atrribute, than jQuery validate handles this as empty or not given.

```
<select class="required"><option>Select here someting</option></select>
```

You can add 'required' as class to your selectbox so jQuery validate will promt a "required" warning.