# Asp.net Routing Url conversion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, routes

Lets say I have this sql server table :

```
id   Name      Band
--------------------
1    John      Beatles
2    Paul      Beatles
3    George    Beatles
4    Ringo     Beatles 
5    Jim       Doors
```

I want to have a person details page like :

`http://localhost/Music/Beatles/Paul`

and I want to treat is as :

`http://localhost/Details.aspx?id=2`

And so- I'm writing this code to register a simple route :

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("MyRoute", "Music/{Band}/{Name}", "~/Details.aspx");
}
```

But I don't understand :

When Asp.net get `http://localhost/Music/Beatles/Paul` , **how** does he know it knows that Paul's value is `2` ?

Are you telling me that each time asp.net encounters `Paul` he should go to DB and scan a pre-defined unique column (`Name` in this case) and get it's column `ID` value?

**Or Should I inject** Paul's value into the url like SO doing :

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938994/jquery-conditional-validation-based-on-select-text 
                                       ^
                                       |
---------------------------------------
```

which will be in my case :

`http://localhost/Music/Beatles/2/Paul`

Comment: You should have a look at AttributeRouting. https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.net does not intrinsicly know that Paul's ID is `2`.

You would have to write this logic somewhere yourself.  You could write your own `RouteHandler` and do the routing yourself (which would do the db call to determine the proper ID).

Personally, I would just let the aspx page handle the information itself and not assume it is given an actual ID.

Here's a code sample of a custom route handler (taken from [Friendly URLs for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340/friendly-urls-for-asp-net))

```
public class CustomRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string virtualPath = "~/path/to/page.aspx";

        int id;

        // this would obviously be some sort of database call
        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["Name"] == "Paul") 
        {
            id = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            id = 8675309;
        }

        string newPath = string.Format(
            "{0}?id={1}",
            virtualPath,
            id
        );


        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(newPath);

        return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler;
    }
}
```

And to register the route

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add("MyCustomRoute", new Route("Music/{Band}/{Name}", new CustomRouteHandler());
```

Comment: What about my other solution ? ( inject the id into the URL like SO does ) ?

Comment: You would make a custom route handler to do that.

Comment: you aren't clear :-). when injecting the id into the url  - i dont need to scan the db. BUT when writing only paul and scanning DB  - this is totaly another thing. what should I do ?

Comment: Take a look at http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/iroutehandler-aspnet-mvc, you would modify the code in `GetHttpHandler` to perform the Paul-to-2 conversion, and load up the asp page with the proper arguments.

Comment: Sorry.:-) but how would i do it in the web-form example ? ( where). thanks.

Comment: I gave a better example in my original example, I'm not sure if it compiles, however.

Comment: P.s. - please notice that if I want to call a page with pauls data - i will need extra round trip to DB  - just to get Paul's value   .Also it will require me that the name column in the DB will be unique.I think the best solution is to add the id into the URL  - just like StackOverflow does. and so - I will be able to enjoy both worlds...(not enforcing unique column , got already the ID , friendly url) what  do you say ?

Comment: I agree, for projects I work on, I just use the ID in urls, for example: `http://mysite.com/2-Beatles-Paul` where you both have a textual URL and the ID in it.