# HTML conditional-based validation of the select option doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to validate my `select` option list in HTML.
The full code is available here:

https://jsfiddle.net/crgfp8ud/

Where I want to distinguish the one option, which will make the other query below active.

I found a couple of solutions:

[Jquery Conditional validation based on select text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938994/jquery-conditional-validation-based-on-select-text)

https://www.py4u.net/discuss/962973

from where I've picked up the code and tried to adapt it for my purposes. Unfortunately they didn't work properly:

```
                                      $(document).ready(function(){
                                        $('input[name=proposed_cable_route]').validate({
                                        rules: {
                                            cname: { required: true },
                                            select1: { valueNotEquals: "0" },
                                            other: { required: function(element){
                                                                return $("#cf_proposed_cable_route option:selected").text() == "Internal";
                                                                }
                                                }
                                    }  
                                    });
```

and the other one

```
                                      /*
                                            $('select').change(function() {
                                            var text = $('select option:selected').text();​​​​​​​​​
                                            if(text == 'Internal') {
                                                $('input[name=building_post_2000]').attr('disabled', true);        
                                                }
                                            });
                                            */
```

the last one tried was:

```
                          $("input[name=proposed_cable_route]").on('select', function() {
                                            var blockNumber = $('#cf_building_post_2000');
                                            // if is company
                                                if ($(this).val() == "Internal") {
                                                    // show panel
                                                    blockNumber.show();
    
                                                    // remove disabled prop
                                                    
                       blockNumber.find('input,select,radio').prop('disabled', false);
                                                } else {
                                                    // if is not company, hide the panel and 
                                         add disabled prop
                                                    //blockNumber.hide();
                                                    blockNumber.find("input").val("");
                                                    
                          blockNumber.find('input,select,radio').prop('disabled', true);
                                                }
                                        });
```

Is there any way to make the validation based on the `select` `option value`?

Comment: how many drop downs do you have on the screen ... var text = $('select option:selected').text();​​​​​​​​​ ... this doesn't capture the relevant one...it just gets the first one

Comment: I have got 3 dropdowns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do the trick.  It gets the currently relevant SELECT and gets its value:

```
$('#cf_proposed_cable_route').change(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    console.log(text);
    $('input[name=building_post_2000]').prop("disabled", text === 'Internal');
});
```

Comment: changed attr to prop...note that the selector should be changed if you have more than one SELECT on the page

Comment: It doesn't work. I think the question id is missing here.

Comment: I used something like this: $('#cf_proposed_cable_route:select').change(function() { but still with no result

Comment: @MKR - fixed with val and the id..please check updates

Answer (score 1):

- i think that you don't need to `select` event you just need to `change` event when you select one option the value of select tag will be change to be the same value of selected option

**For Example**

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi:</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
  </select>
```

> JS Validation

```
var sel = $("select");
sel.change(function () {
  var opt = $("select option:checked")
  if(opt.text() === "BMW") {
     console.log(opt.text())
  }
});
```

- or you can create a loop

> Example

```
var sel = $("select");
sel.change(function () {
  for(var i = $("option").length; i >= 1; i--) {
    if($(this).val() === $("option:nth-child("+i+")").val()) {
      if($("option:nth-child("+i+")").text() === "BMW") {
         console.log($("option:nth-child("+i+")").text())
       }
    }
  }
});
```